# How to find index position of an element in a list when contains returns true

Tags: java

I've got a `List` of `HashMap` so I'm using `List.contains` to find out if the list contains a specified `HashMap`. In case it does, I want to fetch that element from the list, so How do I find out index position of where the element is?

```
    List benefit = new ArrayList();
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("one", "1");
    benefit.add(map);
    HashMap map4 = new HashMap();
    map4.put("one", "1");

    System.out.println("size: " + benefit.size());
    System.out.println("does it contain orig: " + benefit.contains(map));
    System.out.println("does it contain new: " + benefit.contains(map4));

    if (benefit.contains(map4))
        //how to get index position where map4 was found in benefit list?
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

```
benefit.indexOf(map4)
```

It either returns an index or -1 if the items is not found.

I **strongly** recommend wrapping the map in some object and use generics if possible.

Comment: Just a minor comment, in a bottleneck piece of code it's recommended to run list search only once: `int pos = list.indexOf(item); if (pos >= 0) { /* do it */ }`.

Answer (score 16):

[`indexOf(object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

[`get(index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29)

Comment: what about an example? how to use indexOf?

Answer (score 16):

Here is an example:

```
List<String> names;
names.add("toto");
names.add("Lala");
names.add("papa");
int index = names.indexOf("papa"); // index = 2
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `List.indexOf()`.  This will give you the *first* match when there are multiple duplicates.

Comment: what about an example? how to use indexOf?

Answer (score 4):

[List#indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: what about an example? how to use indexOf? w/o a hashmap?

Answer (score 1):

`int   indexOf(Object o)`
This method returns the index in this list of the first occurrence of the specified element, or -1 if this list does not contain this element.

Answer (score -2):

`int indexOf()`  can be used. It returns -1 if no matching finds

Answer (score -3):

Use benefit.indexOf(map4). This should simply return the index of the map or if it doesn't exist it returns -1.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9008566/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*